# Partitioning "Dense_Rank" into quarters (date)

Tags: sql

I have partitioned data the way i want, however now I want supplement it by partitioning it into quarters(date)

I.e actually want to combine the code below with:
"case when date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-03-31' then 'Q1_2020', end as Q_year.
"case when date between '2020-04-01' and '2020-06-30' then 'Q2_2020', end as Q_year.
Then the same grouped by ofc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Gender
      , dense_rank() over (partition by Gender order by ID) 
          + dense_rank() over (partition by Gender order by ID desc)
          - 1 AS Status
      , SUM (Salery) OVER (PARTITION BY Gender) AS Amount
FROM Database1  
WHERE Date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
ORDER BY Gender
```

Any ideas on how to combine "case when then q1" with "dense rank"? I Use dense rank since i have doubletts

Comment: Can you tag the DBMS you're using ..?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)